# Issue with pushing local made changes to github repo

Tags: git, github

I cloned a remote repo called 'X' on my local disk. Then I created 2 new folders inside my local repo X (Precourse and Week1). In the 1st folder (Precourse), I copied all the existing files+folders inside local repo X and in the 2nd folder(Week1), I put some new files of my own.

Some of the commands i used after I had created the new folders and copied stuffs inside them were:

git add *
git commit -m "copying all stuffs in single folder"
git push origin master

The issue was that although the 1st folder(Precourse) is pushed in remote repo along with all the old files+folders inside. However outside thsi folder, the old stuffs still exist (they don't exits in local repo). Also the Week1 folder (newly created) is not pushed well in remote repo and is greyed out. I am unsure  what's happening.
[image: inside master local][image: inside Precourse local][image: origin remote][image: inside Precourse remote]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you said that you've copied all the existing file + folders, i guess you moved it to the Precourse folder.
In that case, you should have used :

```
git mv <source> <destination>
```

Now, if you copied and deleted the files manually, it's possible that Git considered that the content of the "Precourses" folder was "new files" and the deleted files are not added to your commit index.
Run :

```
git status
```

to see if the deleted files are still untracked. Then you will have to run :

```
git add -u
```

and then commit again.